# How to find the install path of git in Mac or Linux?

Tags: linux, git, macos

I want to configure the git in jenkins,but I can't find the install path of git in my mac. can you help me ?

Comment: Could be in `/usr/local/git/`

Comment: That's not a programming question. Belongs on Superuser or Unix/Linux.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Execute in terminal

```
$ which git
```

that produces output

```
/usr/bin/git
```

on Linux. If you are looking for where is install directory on MAC and you installed git with brew then

```
brew info git
```

on Debian

```
dpkg -L git
```

Comment: Or in general you can just pass the result of `which` to `ls -l`

Answer (score 7):

For Linux we can use any of the following commands to find the location of GIT installation directory.

```
1. type git
2. which git
3. command -v git
4. whereis git
```

Comment: Thanks for the set of options